# I want to set random background while opening my android activity for each time.. I tried this way but getting crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In the code below, I passed my image ids in to the array.

I want to set the background random image while open the activity each time

```
public class StickyHome extends Activity {

    int[] imageIds = {R.drawable.sticky,
            R.drawable.sticky1,
            R.drawable.sticky2,
            R.drawable.sticky3,
            R.drawable.sticky4,
            R.drawable.sticky5,
            R.drawable.sticky6,
            R.drawable.sticky7};


    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.colourSticky);
    Random genorator = new Random();
    int randomImageId =imageIds[genorator.nextInt(imageIds.length)];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(randomImageId);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticky_home);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to findViewById before activity created, also before setting content view.

```
int[] imageIds = {R.drawable.sticky,
        R.drawable.sticky1,
        R.drawable.sticky2,
        R.drawable.sticky3,
        R.drawable.sticky4,
        R.drawable.sticky5,
        R.drawable.sticky6,
        R.drawable.sticky7
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticky_home);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.colourSticky);
    Random genorator = new Random();
    int randomImageId =imageIds[genorator.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
    layout.setBackgroundResource(randomImageId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a reference to the `layout` before it's initialized.

Use the following code after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticky_home);` method.

```
layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.colourSticky);
```

You should use any reference to the layout object after the `setContentView()` method.

You should also just set the class variable declaration only as follows.

```
RelativeLayout layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above snippet is correct. But please note that the reason why your application crashes, is because, your calling `findViewById` even before your `Activity` is created. Note that `findViewById` will return `NULL` if you haven't called `setContentView` yet.